# How can i list value labels with numbers from factor (of imported database) in R?

Tags: r, database, dataframe, spss, r-factor

In SPSS, when browsing the variables, I can easily generate a list of value labels with assigned numerical values. This is important when checking, for example, the correctness of encoding questions with the Likert scale.

On the other hand, in R, after importing the data, the variables containing the labels are automatically converted to factors, from which I can not read the codes assigned to them (for all of codes at the same time).

```
library(foreign)
location_dataset = "e:/database.sav"
input_dataset = read.spss(location_dataset, use.value.labels = TRUE, to.data.frame = TRUE)
```

Of course I can only import numeric values

```
input_dataset_numbers = read.spss(location_dataset, use.value.labels = FALSE, to.data.frame = TRUE)
```

i can take head data for some variable:

```
str(input_dataset[,3])
```

levels or number of levels

```
levels(input_dataset[,3])
nlevels(input_dataset[,3])
```

or even take just numerical values:

```
as.integer(input_dataset[,3])
```

but **I am looking for some simple method to review the numeric codes** of a given variable, similar to the one in SPSS, I would like the effect to be something like this:

```
> 1 = definitely not
> 2 = probably not
> 3 = I have no opinion
> 4 = rather yes
> 5 = definitely yes
```

It might be a text output, but maybe one can make an array of it? I have no idea how to combine these things with some simple function, please advice.

Comment: Have a look at the `haven` package to read from SPSS which preserves the codes via the `labelled_spss` class and also allows to deal with different NA values. See e.g. https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/read_spss.html#ref-examples

Comment: OK, i made something like this with this solution: df <- read_spss('location') | a <- df$variablename | labels <- attributes(a)$labels and thats work for me. Note that this attributes function will return NULL if variable don't have labels.

Comment: Could be nice if you post this as an answer to your question with better code formatting

Comment: On my way to make it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the solution from @stefan, I developed such code in R that solves the case for me and allows me to work on these labels.

```
# we need this library, not foreign 
library(haven)
# use your own spss file
location_dataset = "e:/database.sav"
df <- read_spss(location_dataset)
# here we can get names of variables
names(df)
# i got variable "sex", so i can pick it like that: df$variable_name
variable <- df$sex
variable
> <labelled<double>[60]>: Płeć
>  [1] 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2
> [39] 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2
> 
> Labels:
> value  label
>      1   f
>      2   m
# now we can get variable labels (if there are any) to a numeric vector
labels <- attributes(variable)$labels
labels
>  f  m 
>  1  2
```

If the variable has no labels, the command

```
labels <- attributes(variable)$labels
labels
```

will return NULL. I hope this solution will be usefull to someone.